# My <a> links are failing to respond after I attach jquery code to create expandable menus

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am a web developer in php, html and css. Recently I tried to create expandable menus and they really worked using the code below, however whenever I create a link inside the `<ul>` with class 'expList the links will not respond, rather they will only open when I right-click and open on a new tab.

```js
function prepareList() {
  $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
   .click( function(event) {
    if (this == event.target) {
     $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
     $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
    }
    return false;
   })
   .addClass('collapsed')
   .children('ul').hide();
  };
 
  $(document).ready( function() {
      prepareList();
  });
```

```css
#listContainer{
  margin-top:15px;
}
 
#expList ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 18;
}
#expList p {
    margin:0;
    display:block;
}
#expList p:hover {
    background-color:#121212;
}
#expList li {
    line-height:140%;
    text-indent:0px;
    background-position: 1px 8px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
 
/* Collapsed state for list element */
#expList .collapsed {
    background-image: url(../img/collapsed.png);
}
/* Expanded state for list element
/* NOTE: This class must be located UNDER the collapsed one */
#expList .expanded {
    background-image: url(../img/expanded.png);
}
```

```html
<div id="ListContainer">
  <ul id="expList">
<li><img src="/images/dashboard.jpg" height="35" width="35" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Dashboard</li>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<li><img src="/images/chat-.jpg" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Messaging
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/quick-message">Single message</a></li>
    <li><a href="quick-message">Multiple Messages</a></li>
    <li>Overview</li>
    <li>Message Templates</li>
```

Comment: `return false` will stop the default handling of the event. As they bubble from the link to the LI, that will stop the link firing.

Comment: In your code `expList` is an id and not class. If you are creating elements with same Id then this wil create problem

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: That id is on the UL, not the LIs, so it is correct.

Comment: You have `<br/>` elements in your `ul`, outside of any `li`s. Run the W3C validator on your page.

Answer (score 1):

You are always stopping the event handler with `return false`. This will apply to clicks bubbled from the links.

Put the `return false` inside the toggle check:

```
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
            $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
            return false;
        }
```

For efficiency I would suggest you use a delegated event handler instead, attached to your UL. e.g. like:

```
  function prepareList() {
    $('#expList').on('click', 'li:has(ul)', function(event) {
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded').children('ul').toggle('medium');
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('#expList li:has(ul)').addClass('collapsed').children('ul').hide();
  };
```

This version only attaches to one element and applies the descendent selector at *event time* (so it also support dynamically added elements, should you ever need that).